# Dynamically add header to retrofit client builder

Tags: android, retrofit2

Here init of my retrofit client:

```
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
 private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(some_url_here)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(httpClient.build());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    public static <T> T createRestClient(Class<T> restClientClass) {
        retrofit = builder.build();
        return retrofit.create(restClientClass);
    }

    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Nice it's work fine.

But after my application is run and after success finish first http request (e.g. login method) I need to add header to **all of the next http requests**.
Is it possible to this dynamically only after success finish first http request?

Comment: Yes it can be done using intercepter. You can check if first request is done and all the subsequent request will have chained headers before proceeding

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it by doing this for example:

```
Call<String> nexthttpCall(@Header("user-key") String header);
```

You have to include the header at every call.

Or you could add an intercepter to your webclient. This will add to every call the header for example:

```
class HeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.run {
        proceed(
            request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("appid", "hello")
                .addHeader("deviceplatform", "android")
                .removeHeader("User-Agent")
                .build()
        )        
    }
}
```